# ¿Cómo puedo resolver este problema en python?

Tags: python, condiciones

El problema es "Desarrollar un programa que pida un número, si este es mayor que 100 y además es un número par, muestre el mensaje "Cumple condiciones", en caso contrario, deberá mostrar el mensaje "No cumple condiciones".

Solo eh echo el siguiente código:

```
número_1 = input("Digite un número")
if numero_1 > 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- No pongas acentos a la definición de variables
- Te faltaba añadir otra condición al condicional, que es que al dividir el número por 2, que el modulo sea 0 , o sea el numero es par.

```
numero_1 = int(input("Digite un número: "))
if numero_1 > 100 and  numero_1 % 2 == 0:
    print('Cumple condiciones')
else:
    print('No cumple condiciones')
```